# Exercise 6.6.6 In Weibel's "An introduction to homological algebra"

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, homological-algebra

> Exercise 6.6.6 If $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $\mu_m$ denotes the subgroup of $k^*$ consisting of $m$-th roots of unity in $k$, show that $H^2(G;\mu_m)\cong H^2(G;k^*)$ for every finite subgroup $G$ of automorphisms of $k$ order $m$. *Hint:* Consider the "Kummer" sequence $\displaystyle 0 \to \mu_m \to k^* \xrightarrow{m} k^* \to 1.$

I am trying to do this exercise following the hint. By the long cohomology exact sequence attached to the Kummer sequence and our assumption that $\# G = m$, it suffices to show that $H^1(G;k^*) = 0$, and here is where I am stuck:

If $k/k^G$ is Galois, then $\mathrm{Gal}(k|k^G)=G$ and $H^1(G;k^*) = 0$ by Hilbert's Theorem $90$.

**Question:** what if $k/k^G$ is not Galois, or is it always the case that $k/k^G$ is Galois for algebraically closed $k$ and finite subgroup $G\subset \mathrm{Aut}(k)$?
Could anybody answer this question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Artin's Theorem states: "Let $K$ be a field and let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $K$, with $|G|=n$. Let $k=K^G$ be the fixed field of $G$. Then $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $k$, and its Galois gropu is $G$."  E.g., Theorem VI.1.8 in Lang's *Algebra*, revised 3rd Edition; or Theorem V.2.15 in Hungerford's *Algebra*. So $k/k^G$ is always a Galois extension with Galois group equal to $G$.

Comment: Note that for Artin's Theorem it doesn't matter if the field you start with is algebraically closed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I dropped the use of the $n$; the statement in Lang also has $[K:K^G]=n$ as part of the statement, as it happens before proving the full Fundamental Theorem.